# How to check whether the connection is alive or not in RabbitMq node-amqplib library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I am writing producer & consumer using rabbitMq node-amqplib library, I am afraid about suddenly to lost connection of server , How could I check whether the connection is alive or not ?

Comment: Connect with RabbitMQ Web UI Server. You can achieve this with the plugin. This might help:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html
There you can see bindings between producer & consumer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMQP 0-9-1 offers a heartbeat feature to ensure that the application layer promptly finds out about disrupted connections (and also completely unresponsive peers).

In amqplib you only need to set a heartbeat timeout (non 0) when you call `connect([url, [socketOptions]])` and the check will be performed automatically.

More info here:

https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#heartbeating

http://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply ,,kindly mention one more thing , could I keep connection alive with server by using heartbeat or by any other exclusive way that I can implement?

Comment: You can only keep the connection alive using heartbeats (it is the way RabbitMQ works). Note that every message you send or receive also count as a heartbeat. So if you send arbitrary messages, the connection will be kept alive.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options in doing this:

One way is using the heartbeat and an event listener, something like
`conn.on('close', (err) => { this.connected = false; } )`

Or you can get into the connection object. There is a risk here as upgrades to  amqplib may break this, as it's not part of the official interface:
`const connClosed = conn.connection['expectSocketClose']`

There are other properties inside the connection object that also can tell you if it's closed, like stream writeable state (could be a false flag) or the heartbeater object.